# iphone xcode - Twitter api or snippet

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, twitter

I've seen a few "Share" twitter or FB on some iphone. Is there any framework or SDK for this or some code snippet to copy from.

I dont want to write it from scratch if there is something already available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/) is very easy to configure and use and supports Facebook, Twitter, and many other services.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [MGTwitterEngine](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine).

Comment: Tutorial URL is broken. would you fix it please.. :)

Comment: Oh dear, the blog that had the tutorial now appears to be full of spammy crap. Have removed the tutorial link. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use facebook-ios-sdk for Fb and Twitter.framework for twitter.